# Keras gives an exact result, not a distribution of confidence between classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm building a Keras model, which is a binary classifier. It is a retrained Xception model. Here is my model code:

```
from keras.applications.xception import Xception, preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model

base_model = Xception(input_shape=(300, 300, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='prediction')(x)
model = Model(base_model.input, predictions)
```

The problem is: when I train it, it gives the result like so:

```
array([[1., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

So a '1' for one class and '0' for the other. How do I make it display the distribution of confidence? Something like '0.913' for one class and '0.087' for the other?

P.S. here's how I predict:

```
img_width=300
img_height=300

img = image.load_img('processed_dataset/test/EM/bull_212.jpg', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

images = np.vstack([x])
model.predict(images, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: Something might have gone wrong with your training, such as a very high unbalace in classes, or wrong labels. There is no aparent reason for your values to be exact (they're probably truncated).

Comment: You can verify that your code should give class probabilities by running `model.predict(np.random.rand(1, 300, 300, 3))`. As said, probably something went wrong during training.

Comment: @sdcbr I ran the code, it gives the distribution I need! That really gives me hope! Now I probably need to know what went wrong with how I give the actual image to the classifier. Do you have any guesses?